# haskell recording positions function

Tags: function, haskell, position

im trying to write a function which will return  a list with all the positions from the starting point. For example if i write 
"positions [L,R,L,L,U] (0,0)" the out come must be "[(0,0),(-1,0),(0,0),(-1,0),(-2,0),(-2,1)]" .

with the following function i only get the ending position. Can anyone help me?

```
type Position = (Int,Int)
data Step = L | R | U | D

type Route = [Step]

positions :: Route -> Position-> [Position]
positions [] p = p:[]
positions (m:ms) p = positions ms (move m p)
```

Comment: You can define a function that specifies one moment, and then use `scanl`.

Answer (score 2):

Your code suggests that you thus already defined a function `move :: Step -> Position -> Position`, we can then use [**`scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl):

```
positions :: [Step] -> Position -> [Position]
positions = flip (scanl (flip move))
```

`scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]` takes thus as input a function (here `flip move`) that is given the initial accumulator (here a `Position`) and an element of the list (the list of moves), and calculates the updated accumulator. We then give it the initial accumulator and the list of positions.

Since our `move :: Step -> Position -> Position` and `positions :: [Step] -> Position -> [Position]` function have flipped arguments (w.r.t. `scanl`), we both flip the `move` function, and the function that we constructed with `scanl (flip move)`.

Comment: yes i do have a move function but when im trying to define the scanl i have the error "  The type signature for ‘scanl’ lacks an accompanying binding
      (The type signature must be given where ‘scanl’ is declared)

Comment: @PinelopiConstantinou: you do not need to define `scanl`, `scanl` is a prelude function.

Comment: Why are you trying to define `scanl`? It's a library function.

Comment: oh okay now i understand what is happening! thank you very much! :D